# Is adding 0 to a null pointer UB?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, null-pointer

I’m quite sure this question has been asked before, but I just couldn’t find it.

If I have a pointer that is null, e.g. a `char*` initialized to `nullptr`, is it undefined behavior (UB) to add `0` to it? I haven’t actually found any claim that adding anything to a null pointer is UB, but I’d guess adding anything except `0` for sure is UB.

```cpp
char* buf = nullptr;
buf += 0; // UB?
```

This is of course not my actual code, but I have pointer–length pairs that could end up `(nullptr, 0)`. Some functions modify this pair without dereferencing the pointer and could end up adding `0` to a null pointer. Do I need to protect these by an `if (ptr != nullptr)` or would that be wasted lines of code?

---

I know that executing UB leads to a compile error in `constexpr` evaluation, so I tried this:

```cpp
static_assert([](char* buf){ buf += 0; return buf == nullptr; }(nullptr) == true);
static_assert([](char* buf){ buf += 1; return buf == nullptr; }(nullptr) == false);
```

The latter fails to compile (messages below) because I add `1` to a null pointer (as expected), but the first `static_assert` is fine on all compilers I tried (GCC 12.1.0, Clang 15.0.0, and MSVC 19.34.31942). Does this mean that it is in fact not UB to add `0` to a null pointer or does it only prove that it is defined in those compilers?

Messages:

- GCC: “arithmetic involving a null pointer”
- Clang: “cannot perform pointer arithmetic on null pointer”
- MSVC build: “failure was caused by unevaluable pointer value”
- MSVC IntelliSense: “invalid arithmetic on non-array pointer”

Comment: [expr.add](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.add): "If P evaluates to a null pointer value and J evaluates to 0, the result is a null pointer value."

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38526510/the-nullptr-and-pointer-arithmetic selected answer + some comments.

Comment: Does the approach of executing the instruction in question in a `constexpr` context actually work or was I lucky (give or take compiler bugs)?

Comment: this answer covers your case https://stackoverflow.com/a/38527263/4117728

Comment: None of the answers on the dupe target reference the standard so I added an answer that does so you can have that information if needed.